# Irreducible markov chain with all transient states

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I was doing a question set by my tutor asking to find an irreducible markov chain where all the states were transient.

It's my understanding that is a markov chain is irreducible, all the states must communicate with each other inside the class $C$, i.e
$$
(\forall i,j\in C)( \exists  n_1 , n_2 \in\mathbb{N})\left[P_{i,j}^{n_1} ,P_{j,i}^{n_2}>0\right]
$$
Hence if the class is irreducible, every element in the state space should be able to communicate with each other.

But if a state $k$ is transient, then it won't return back to $k$?
Furthermore, the example she gave was:

- State space $\mathbb{N}$
- Transition probabilities : $P_{i,i+1}=1;  \ \ \ \ \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$

I don't think this is even irreducible! Surely this is split up into classes $\{1\}\cup\{2\}\cup\{3\}\cup\ \cdots \cup\{n\}\cup \cdots $ ?

Have I just got my definitions wrong?

Comment: In the example given. all states in the markov chain given are indeed transient, but the MC is not irreducible. for irreducibility, all states, by  definition must communicate. In this case, you can't come back to any state. Further, they don't all belong to one equivalence class.

Comment: The standard random walk on $\mathbb Z^3$ is irreducible and transient.  The walk returns to any given point only finitely many times so that it goes to $\infty$ (almost surely).  It is interesting that the standard random walks on $\mathbb Z^2$ and $\mathbb Z$ are recurrent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are right. The MC that you have mentioned with $P_{i,i+1}=1$ is not irreducible. For example, you can not go from state $5$ to state $4$. It is transient though.
2. You can consider the follow MC. state-space $S:=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, $P_{0,1} =1$, $P_{i,i+1}=0.9$, and $P_{i,i-1}=0.1$ for $i=1,2,\ldots$. This is both irreducible and transient.

Comment: How is the chain in your second point transient? Does it have something to do with going to infinity? Also are there any finite Markov chains that are irreducible and have transient states?

Comment: Yes, it has something to do with going to infinity. The point is that you can show that the MC will leave every point, and drift off to infinity with probability one. For a formal proof please look up why a random walk is transient when $p\neq 1/2$. Also, all irreducible finite-state MCs are recurrent. Let me know if it is clear. Best